# Múltiplas instâncias Access

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Como se abre múltiplas instâncias de um mesmo Banco do Access, eu vi que um antigo companheiro de trabalho utilizava o comando:

`Shell "MSACCESS.EXE " & Chr(34) & CurrentDb.Name & Chr(34)`

Porém ao executar me retorna um erro dizendo que o Banco já está aberto em modo 'Admin' por outro usuário, que no caso sou eu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solução

Depois de muito bater a cabeça descobri como fazer.

Basta ir em **Arquivo > Opções > Configurações do Cliente**

E deixar as opções avançadas dessa forma:

[image: Opções > Configurações do Cliente > Avançado]